# Как правильно создать форму с глобальным ключем внутри роута навигатора в Flutter?

Tags: форма, роутинг, flutter, dart

Всем привет! Англоязычная часть StackOverflow не смогла ответить на мой вопрос или дело сыграл англоязычный барьер :(, поэтому пишу тут:
Проблема в следующем - имеется приложение (заготовка), с поименным роутингом. В одном из роутов рендерится виджет с формой авторизации, у этой формы есть глобальный ключ, у каждого из полей формы тоже есть глобальный ключ (ключи, конечно, разные у всех).

Проблема в следующем - при нахождении данного компонента (страницы с формой) внутри роута, при тапе по полю формы вызывается перерендер роута, если при этом ключи генерируются внутри данного компонента (где-то внутри builder-функции роута) - то предыдущий инстанс компонента уничтожается, и тут же создается новый, что приводит к невозможности пользоваться компонентом с формой. Если глобальные ключи хранить вне builder-функции, то форма также ререндерится при любом тапе по полям формы, однако состояние фокуса на поле сохраняется, но т.к. компонент перебилдился, а ключи хранятся выше в дереве - то возникает ошибка использования одного ключа в разных компонентах.

Подскажите, как можно использовать формы к глобальными ключами в приложении с роутингом, и не собирать такие грабли?

К вопросу прикладываю два видео (мои), где очень наглядно демонстрируется проблема и виден реальный код, огромная просьба - посмотрите их. Также прикладываю код в виде картинки, потому что есть непонятные траблы с код-вставкой тут. Также оставлю ссылку на EN-версию данного вопроса, может она поможет.

Отчет доктора:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[v] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.2.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.253], locale ru-RU)
[v] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[v] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[v] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.30.2)
[v] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Код "приложения":

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mobx/flutter_mobx.dart';
import 'package:quich/controllers/user_controller.dart';
import 'package:quich/route/routes.dart';
import 'package:quich/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:quich/screens/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:quich/store/app_store.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(Quich());
  await $store.storage.ready;
  var uc = UserController();
  var isValid = await uc.isTokenValid(token: 'token');
  $store.isAuth = isValid;
  $store.isLoading = false;
}

class Quich extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => _QuichState();
}

class _QuichState extends State<Quich> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Регистрация',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: Routes.splash,
      routes: {
        Routes.splash: (context) => Observer(builder: (_) {
          return SplashScreen();
        }),
        Routes.login: (context) {
          print('SUPER PARENT BUILD');
          return LoginScreen();
          final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
          final fieldKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
          return Scaffold(
            body: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Form(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: controller,
                      key: fieldKey
                    ),
                  ),
                  key: formKey,
                ),
                ButtonBar(
                  children: [
                    MaterialButton(
                      child: Text('Проверка', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Routes.splash),
                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Небольшое пояснение по тому, что происходит на видео - при тапе по кнопке "Проверка" - происходит переход на роут экрана загрузки, а потом авто-возврат на роут "авторизации".

P.S. В код-редакторе в английской версии съедаются типы для глобальных ключей и для State-класса приложения, поэтому все ответы сосредоточены на ошибке в этом, однако в реальном коде все отлично.

P.P.S Проблема решилась случайно, и крылась, скорее всего, в том, что поля формы генерировались функцией.
Полный код компонента с формой:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quich/blocs/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:quich/models/auth_model.dart';
import 'package:quich/services/validators.dart';
import 'package:quich/states/auth_state.dart';
import 'package:quich/ui/extended_form_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class Auth extends StatefulWidget {
  final AuthBloc bloc;
  Auth({@required this.bloc});

  @override
  _AuthState createState() => _AuthState();
}

//Builder-функция, создающая проблему
Widget buildTextField({@required String title, IconData icon, Function validator, TextInputType type, String field, TextEditingController controller, GlobalKey<FormFieldState> key, String error, bool hidden}) {
  Widget create() {
    return ExtendedFormField(title: title, controller: controller, icon: icon, fieldKey: key, type: type, validator: validator, error: error, hidden: hidden);
  }

  return create();
}

class _AuthState extends State<Auth> {
  final _controllerEmail = TextEditingController();
  final _controllerPhone = TextEditingController();
  final _controllerPassword = TextEditingController();
  final _controllerFts = TextEditingController();

  AuthBloc get _bloc => widget.bloc;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool _isCompleteLoading = false;
  GlobalKey<FormState> fk;

  List<Color> notLoginGradients = [Colors.blue, Colors.deepPurple];
  List<Color> loginGradients = [Colors.green, Colors.green[900]];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          BlocBuilder<dynamic, AuthState>(
              bloc: _bloc,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AuthState state) {
                final _authFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
                this.fk = _authFormKey;
                final _keyEmail = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
                final _keyPhone = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
                final _keyPassword = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
                final _keyFts = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();

                return Form(
                  key: _authFormKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      buildTextField(title: 'Email', icon: Icons.email, validator: isEmail, type: TextInputType.emailAddress, field: 'email', controller: _controllerEmail, key: _keyEmail, error: state.emailError),
                      buildTextField(title: 'Телефон', icon: Icons.phone_android, validator: isPhone, type: TextInputType.phone, field: 'phone', controller: _controllerPhone, key: _keyPhone, error: state.phoneError),
                      buildTextField(title: 'Пароль', icon: Icons.security, validator: isTooShort, type: TextInputType.text, field: 'password', controller: _controllerPassword, key: _keyPassword, error: state.passwordError, hidden: true),
                      buildTextField(title: 'Код ФНС', icon: Icons.code, validator: isTooShort, type: TextInputType.text, field: 'code', controller: _controllerFts, key: _keyFts, error: state.codeError),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }),
          Container(
              height: 60,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: LinearGradient(colors: this._isCompleteLoading ? this.loginGradients : notLoginGradients), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
              child: Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  shadowColor: Color.fromRGBO(100, 181, 246, 0.5),
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  elevation: 10,
                  child: InkWell(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      splashColor: Colors.blue[900],
                      onTap: () {
                        if (fk.currentState.validate()) {
                          _bloc.dispatch(AuthModel(phone: _controllerPhone.text, email: _controllerEmail.text, password: _controllerPassword.text, code: _controllerFts.text));
                        }
                      },
                      child: Center(
                          child: BlocBuilder<dynamic, AuthState>(
                              bloc: _bloc,
                              builder: (BuildContext context, AuthState state) {
                                if (state.isLoading == true) {
                                  return CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white));
                                } else {
                                  return Text('ВОЙТИ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white));
                                }
                              }))))),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
            child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Очень успешно')));
                },
                child: Text('Зарегистрироваться', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black26))),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Ссылки:

[En-версия](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575907/why-flutter-rerender-widget-wich-contain-a-textformfield-with-own-key)

[Video 1](https://youtu.be/B5CYmYTtCLU)

[Video 2](https://youtu.be/CUAxX6Jz2rY)

[Video 3](https://youtu.be/IGpnojFO9zM)

[Image with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgWeq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется основная проблема в том что в билдере Routes.login нужно вынести экран в отдельный statefullWidget и там, для начала, реализовать все как в примере https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/forms/validation
Только недавно делал подобное у себя, но корневой виджет экрана stateless а внутри 
statefull widget с полями ввода

```
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/login';

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return SafeArea(
              child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(flex: 1, child: Center(child: Logo())),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50.0),
                  child: LoginForm(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginFormState createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final _loginFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _phoneNumberLength = 10;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _loginFormKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            maxLines: 1,
            maxLength: _phoneNumberLength,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            decoration:
                InputDecoration(prefixText: '+7 ', labelText: 'Телефон', icon: Icon(Icons.phone)),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty || value.length != _phoneNumberLength) {
                return 'Введите номер телефона';
              }
            },
          ),
          PasswordTextField(),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
                color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text(
                  'Войти'.toUpperCase(),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_loginFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    _login();
                  }
                }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _login() {
    LoginBlocProvider.of(context).userEvents.add(LoginBlocUserEvent.login);
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за идею, проблема оказалась не в этом.
Я не учел того, что компонент авторизации - форма с полями, имела функцию, которая возвращала эти самые поля, функция - обертка над классом-оберткой над полем формы. Благодаря вашему ответу я решил переписать этот компонент с 0, и в итоге обратил внимание на этот момент и избавившись от него - решил проблему.

P.S. Помещение условного компонента-формы в виде Statefull виджета внутрь Stateless виджета, который будет возвращать WidgetBuilder Navigator'а - не влияет на проблему (можно делать генерируемые билдером виджет и Statefull - см. Video 3).